# Counting with AND/OR in one column

Tags: excel-2010, worksheet-function

This is my first question on this forum and I apologize in advance if it's messy or doesn't seem useful....I'll keep working at it and I'll get the hang of it soon!

I've looked online and in Excel help for this but all I can find is using AND/OR statements with two columns (which seem easy), nothing with AND/OR within one column.

Column D describes failures.  I am looking to count the number of instances that the word "seal" or bearing" shows up by cell but there are some occasions where both are in one cell.  I would like one count to happen regardless of the words bearing and seal occurring in the same cell otherwise I could use COUNTIF(range,*seal*)+COUNTIF(range,*bearing*).  Can someone help me by describing the statement I need to not count some cells twice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIF(range,"*seal*")+COUNTIF(range,"*bearing*")-COUNTIFS(range,"*seal*",range,"*bearing*")
```

The `COUNTIFS` acts as you describe, to remove the double counted elements.